# How can I know which color channel is each element of the array returned by the read function in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

Using OpenCV with Python binding, when executing the following code:

```
import cv2


cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')

while (cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    # ...

# ...
```

How can I know which color channel is in each of `frame[:, :, 0]`, `frame[:, :, 1]` and `frame[:, :, 2]`. I mean, is RGB, RBG, GBR, GRB, BRG or BGR?

Thank you very much!

Comment: OpenCV reads colored images with `BGR` channel order by default.

Comment: @sgarizvi thank you very much!

Comment: If it helps, please accept an answer below so that the issue can be marked as solved. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, OpenCV reads colored images with `BGR` channel order. So `frame[:, :, 0]` is **B**, `frame[:, :, 1]` is **G** and `frame[:, :, 2]` is **R**.

Answer (score 2):

In OPENCV, the default color format should be BGR or BGRA.